# How do I check the android version for my app to set an alternative directory?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So I have this code where I want to get some files in a certain app directory, but on android 11, this app directory is not the same as the old versions, how do i modify my code to check this and get all versions right directories:

````
```val bool = sharedPref.getBoolean("dwaBool",false)

    val oldPath = if (bool){
        Constants.STATUS_LOCATION_DW
    }else{
        Constants.STATUS_LOCATION
    }
````

the right directory for android 11 is in a "const val" called "STATUS_LOCATION_AVERS"

Comment: The question title does not really match the goal of finding the app directory location by Android version. This might be misleading. There are hundreds of answers for how to find the android version of your app. I'd suggest to update the title to be more meaningful.

Comment: I'm sure it is all right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this snippet

```
val oldPath = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30){
       // android 11 or higher
        Constants.STATUS_LOCATION_DW
    }else{
        Constants.STATUS_LOCATION
    }
```

Comment: But like, my codes looks likes this `val bool = sharedPref.getBoolean("dwaBool",false)

        val oldPath = if (bool){
            Constants.STATUS_LOCATION_DW
        }else{
            Constants.STATUS_LOCATION
        ` wold not it be left over the variable "bool"?

Answer (score 1):

`BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE` gives the current version integer number of the app.